# Datehistogram aggregate returns empty buckets

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to aggregate some data by day to make some charts but the datehistogram aggregate return only empty bucket.

My data look like:

```
Date: July 2nd 2019, 12:08:50.647
_id: 4959287196855971761665003616
```

And my Nest request :

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

var descriptor = new SearchDescriptor<ModelWrapper>()
                .Index("command-*")
                .AllTypes()
                .From(0)
                .Size(100)
                .Sort(s => s.Descending("Date"))
                .Aggregations(a => a
                    .DateHistogram("daily", v => v
                        .Field(p => p.Date)
                        .Interval(DateInterval.Day)
                        .ExtendedBounds(now.AddMonths(-2), now)
                       ))
```

When I make the request on the kibana console:

```
{
"aggs" : {
        "daily" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "Date",
                "interval" : "1D",
                "extended_bounds": {
                  "min": "2019-06-02T12:01:02.123",
                  "max": "2019-07-02T12:01:02.123"
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the expected result.

I'm on Nest 6.2 and Elastic 6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some fiddling around I used this piece of code to serialize my SearchDescriptor to the sent string:

```
  var json = m_client.RequestResponseSerializer.SerializeToString(descriptor);
```

which got me:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "daily": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "extended_bounds": {
                    "max": "2019-07-02T16:25:57.522217",
                    "min": "2019-05-02T16:25:57.522217"
                },
                "field": "date",
                "interval": "day"
            }
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 100,
    "sort": [{
        "Date": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }]
}
```

The issue here is that my field is put in lowercase, wich is expected behaviour (as pointed out [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/field-inference.html#camel-casing) ).

The solution is to override the DefaultFieldNameInferrer which does this transformation, to do this I added to my connection settings:

```
  var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool);

  settings.DefaultFieldNameInferrer(p => p);
```

And now everything work as expected.

#### Edit:

As noted by [Russ Cam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831/russ-cam) I can also pass a string to Field() so another solution is just to do:

```
  .Field(nameof(ModelWrapper.Date))
```

Comment: You can pass a `string` to `.Field()` too, so could use `.Field(nameof(ModelWrapper.Date))`, without setting `.DefaultFieldNameInferrer(p => p);`